# Firebase App Distribution: "Could not find the APK" (when having built an AAB)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to upload AAB to App Distribution (linked to Google Play) and I'm getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':mobile:appDistributionUploadRelease'.
> Could not find the APK. Make sure you build first by running ./gradlew assemble[Variant*** or set the artifactPath parameter to point to your APK
```

How to resolve the issue without building an APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `artifactType` is by default set to `APK`, but one can change it to `AAB`:

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
    artifactType = "AAB"
    ...
}
```

Source: the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle).